# Unity2D: How to make animate each text character into a wavy effect

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I've done a lot a research on this topic and the solution I found on this matter was [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1094787/animate-text-wavy-text.html) post I found on unity answers, however I wasn't quite sure how I can animate each text character through c#. 
The example given in the post (e.g. Whoosh) is the perfect animation I want to achieve!

Can anyone give me an insight into this matter?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than having the whole word in one `Text` component, you create a separate `Text` component for each letter of the word. Make sure they all have the same parent.

Then you add an `Animator` component on the parent, which will allow you to move all of the letters in the same animation clip, and you should be able to get the effect you want.

Comment: Thank you for replying! Unfortunately I was kinda hoping I was able to achieve this through code, only because of the fact that I have a script that uses a switch statement to randomly pick what I want my text to say, so I don't think that your suggestion will work in that sense. Is it possible to do what I want to do through code or should I still try and do your suggestion but try and figure out a way to make it work?? Thank you again for the help, I really appreciate it!!! :)

Comment: If you want to do it by code, just create a Prefab with a Text component and reference it in your script. Then, when you pass the word you want to animate, you instantiate one prefab for each letter. From this point you can just write a method that changes the Transforms for each of the letters on every Update or FixedUpdate. You'll have to play around with it a bit to figure out how to scale the effect depending on the length of the word.. since you're only moving the letters vertically, it's probably a matter of adjusting the movement factor according to word length, to get that wavy effect.